# Finding how closely a set of strings are related

Tags: php, javascript, algorithm

I have an array of strings(as shown in example). I just wish to find out whats most common among them. Most common string is defined as :-  If  Apple Ipod touch appears 10 times(say) while apple ipod appears 8 times, then I would say Apple Ipod Touch is dominant/common string in all elements.

```
Apple iPod touch, 8GB (with FaceTime Camera and Retina Display)
Aple Ipod Clasic 80gb 6th Generation Black
iPod classic 160GB - Silver
Apple 8GB iPod Touch
Apple Ipod Touch 8gb 4th Generation Mc540ll/a 8 Gb Newest Model
Apple iPod touch Black 4th Generation 8GB Touch Screen Wi-Fi MP3
Apple 8GB iPod touchï¿½
Apple 8GB iPod touch MC540LL/A
Apple MC540LL/A - 8GB iPod Touch w/ Camera (4th Gen) (Newest Model)
Apple iPod Touch - 8 GB - Electronics
Apple iPod 8GB 4th Generation Black Touch
Apple iPod touch 8GB 4th Gen (Refurbished)
Apple Ipod Touch Digital Player - Apple Ios 5
Apple Ipod Touch 8G - White (4Th Gen)
Apple MC540LL/A iPod Touch 8GB (4th Generation)
(refurbished) Apple Ipod Touch 8gb (4th Generation)
Apple Ipod Touch 8Gb 4Th Generation
iPod Touch 8GB (4th Gen)
Apple Ipod Touch 32G - White (4Th Gen)
Apple iPod touch 8GB (4th Gen), White
Apple iPod touch White 4th Generation 8GB Touch Screen Wi-Fi MP3
Apple 32GB Black 4th Generation iPod Touch - MC544LL/A
Apple 8GB iPod touchï¿½
Apple iPod touch 8GB - White - Electronics
Apple MC544LL/A - 32GB iPod Touch w/ Camera (4th Gen) (Newest Model)
```

So, Can anyone suggest me some good algorithms to do that ? The problem is that I don't have any standard/benchmark to compare with. I just need to compare all elements among themselves and find out the most common one.This has to be implemented in PHP or Javascript.

Hope I am clear in my question. Please comment if I am unclear somewhere.

Comment: So you want the substring (probably only full words count) that appears in the most lines? Because that would be `Apple`. Or do you want the longest substring that appears in multiple lines?

Comment: Is the string that you're looking for a whole line or a part of it? Also, is your search case-sensitive or not?

Comment: The string should be longest possible and not case-sensitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have looked at using PHP's `similar_text` function or if there is a similar javascript function. A quick Google search also showed me http://cambiatablog.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/algorithm-for-string-similarity-better-than-levenshtein-and-similar_text/

EDIT: similar_text Javascript function! http://phpjs.org/functions/similar_text:902

Comment: Can I generate a suggestion list out of the above list. What algorithm should i use for that ?